# How to use Pushbullet API on Mikrotik using fetch tool?

Tags: mikrotik, pushbullet

I need Mikrotik to send me a notification via Pushbullet if there is a certain event using fetch

I find some code to work with it, but it sends me an error, I read on the web site about the error code, it says my token was invalid, I tried to create multiple token, but no luck.

`/tool fetch mode=https url="https://api.pushbullet.com/api/pushes" http-method=post http-data="device_iden=<DeviceID>&type=note&body=High priority message from MikroTik device&title=RouterOS Alert" user="<APIKey>"`

I expected the code to send the notification, but I get <401 unauthorized> instead.

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax with Pushbullet:

```
/tool fetch mode=https url="https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes" http-method=post http-data="type=note&body=some text" user="API-Token"
```

On a specific device:

```
/tool fetch mode=https url="https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes" http-method=post http-data="device_iden=<device_id>&type=note&body=some text" user="API-Token"
```